# Optimal way of generating a large sequence of letters for future manipulation

Tags: java, memory, text, random, bit

I'm trying to generate 4 billion instances of random characters ranging from A-H and then storing it all into a text file in Java.  I tried the baseline method of iterating until a counter reaches to 4B but I find that it always results in a memory problem.

I was wondering if it would be more memory efficient to store the letters as bits rather than their primitive values as characters. Such as the following:

```
A <- 000, B <- 001, C <- 010, D <- 011, E <- 100, F <- 101, G <- 110, H <- 111
```

If so, how would I go about doing this?

---

Looking ahead, once I have a text file with all these randomly generated letters, what would the best method be for opening the txt file to make further modifications? e.g. replacing or appending a few characters.
I looked into Java's tutorials and think that the Random Access Files will do the trick, but is there a better option?

Should I add a newline to the character string every n letters to allow the read newline function a stopping point?

I guess to concisely state my questions, it's the following:
How to generate 4Billion random limited letters (not all 26) effectively to a text file so that it can be also read and modified for future use?

Comment: *"..in JAVA"*  No need to add a tag into the title, and note that it is 'Java', not 'JAVA'.

Comment: Sorry about that! Will remember next time.

Comment: +1 for 'will remember next time'.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to optimize storage then use `byte` type. You don't need to change anything since byte can store the letters in their original value.

The best thing to do for the original save is to have a `FileOutputStream` and "page" the generation, for example write every 100 megabytes.

For further file actualization, `RandomAccessFile` is ok. I don't think adding a new line will be any good since you already know the length of every "information unit" you'll have on the file, adding a new line would just duplicate the storage space.

Hope I could make it clear (and makes sense) :)

Tell me how it went.

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for the response. Thanks for the recommendation. I'll be sure to try using the byte type. 

As for the second part, I actually plan on leaving most of it alone, but will be randomly insert a sequence of character strings into the 4Billion sequence. e.g: [random inserted sequence of "EEEEEEE"]
ABCDHHHCB... ...HADCDCHBADC[\EOF]. --> ABCD[EEEEEEE]HHHCB...HADCDCHBADC[\EOF]

Comment: I don't understand the idea of sorting. What has it to do with the question? Sorting the characters from A-H wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Hi Juan, sorry to bug you further, but how would I "page" the data?

Comment: I'll try to explain it with an example: Say you have a 512kb total memory space (like ancient computers) and you want to process a file that is 4mb length, in this case you could create a byte array say with 262144 elements (256k) and load and process the file in chunks (pages) of 256k. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

So you can save 8 different values in 3 bits, that's right. You can therefore store 2x3 bits in a byte, or 8x3 bits in 24/8=3 bytes, while storing them as characters would only mean 3 characters 'A' - 'H' in 24 bits.

That's a saving of 8/3, so 1.5 billion bytes would do. However, to make a short example Assuming you had to store a sequence which isn't dividable by 8, then you would have some unused bytes in you code:

You save BA, which is 001 000, and have to fill the byte to 0010:0000. How would you distinguish it from B? B is just 001, so filled up, it is 0010:0000 too.

Ok. For a file of filelength 1.5 GB, you could just always append a single byte, which tells you, how many bits of the last byte are to be used. In the example above, you would once append 6, once append 3.

But now, if you have to insert something. You shift through the binary sequence always 3 bits, but if there is a non-8-disible insertion, you can't just read the following bytes, and append them to your bitstream, but you would have to transpose every following byte: cut it into 2 peaces, append the first part to your overrun, and keep the second part as overrun for the next byte.

The implementation might not be too tricky - but I don't know how the runtime would be affected.

Maybe a statistical analysis can help. How often are characters appended, and how much. How often inserted at what size?

Maybe it would be more easy to organze the file in chunks - maybe 1000 files of 2MB, each containing a free buffer to append to. The last bytes could specify how many bytes are considered content in the file.

How is the insertion of data specified? Will it be "insert at position 2 713 345 947 the sequence "AHA"? Or will it be "insert after the 3rd sequence of "FACHDAG" "BACH"? Are there typical, often repeated sequences like words in natural language?

In the firsts case, an external index could be very useful. If you could look up, in which of 1000 files the position 2,713,345,947 is, and skipping on average the necessity to read 50% of your 1.5G could improve your speed much.

But you would need statistical analysis: Will the file grow or more or less stay the same size. How often is it read and written. Are updates inserts, appends, deletions.